# Is the new cookie policy from 26 May 2011 enforced?

Tags: cookies, enforcement

I know a new cookie law was suggested (see [here](http://www.ico.gov.uk/for_organisations/privacy_and_electronic_communications/the_guide/cookies.aspx)). But did it ever become required? And what's the penalty for not complying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We have placed cookies on your computer to help make this website better. You can change your cookie settings at any time. Otherwise, we'll assume you're OK to continue.

The ICO's website now shows that users must opt out, not opt in. The quote above shows how they have implemented it on their site.

This means that the best idea is probably to have a banner at the top of your site showing a similar message to theirs. If the user doesn't want to use cookies, they can disable them in the browser themselves. It's not up to the site owner to implement a cookie deletion policy, it would seem.